# Excel VBA For Loop Not Working, Keeps coming up with error message

Tags: vba, excel

Making a single player blackjack simulation but when I run it keeps coming back with the message:

> Compile Error
>
> Next without For

```
    For i = 1 To 5
    
        If win = "False" Then
            Range("C13").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Range("B11").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("C13").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
            
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            
            Range("C18").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-5]C:R[-1]C)"
            Range("C19").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
            Range("H19").Select
    
            If Range("C18") < 22 And Range("C18") >= Range("B18") Then
                win = "True"
            End If
        
            If Range("C18") < 22 Then
                win = "Bust"
        End If
    Next i
    
    If win = "True" Then
        Application.Run "Dealer_wins"
    Else
        Application.Run "player_wins"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: count your Ifs and End Ifs. You are opening 3 If statements in the For Loop but only closing 2 of them.

Comment: One `End If` is missing, right before `Next i` line.

Comment: `Range("C18") >= Range("B18")` this is condition will return `true` anyway, what does it mean in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were simply missing an `End If` for the test on C18!

And I got rid of the useless `.Select` as this is a really resources consuming command that is most of the time absolutely not necessary!

```
    For i = 1 To 5

        If win = "False" Then
            Range("C13").Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Range("B11").Copy

            With Range("C13")
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                            :=False, Transpose:=False
                With .Interior
                    .Pattern = xlNone
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
            End With

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Range("C18").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-5]C:R[-1]C)"
            Range("C19").FormulaR1C1 = ""

            If Range("C18") < 22 And Range("C18") >= Range("B18") Then
                win = "True"
            End If

            If Range("C18") < 22 Then
                win = "Bust"
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If win = "True" Then
        Application.Run "Dealer_wins"
    Else
        Application.Run "player_wins"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: deleted my answer as it was a (not as good) double from yours. Just to add : the OP had an excellent indentation that allowed for quick bug identification. He just has to learn how to use this good habit.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z : You should have let it to still get some upvotes, it is not an issue to have duplicate answers! It might confuse the asker a bit, but it is his job to test what we can propose! ;)
Undelete it so I can upvote your answer and your fair play! ;)

Answer (score 0):

additional variant to already provided:

```
....

For i = 1 To 5
    If win = "False" Then
        With [C13]
            .Insert
            .Value = [B11].Value2
            With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
        [C18].Value = Application.Sum([C13:C17])
        [C19] = ""
        If [C18].Value2 < 22 And [C18].Value2 >= [B18].Value2 Then 'this condition shall be reviewed
            win = "True"
        ElseIf [C18].Value2 < 22 Then
            win = "Bust"
        End If
    End If
Next i
If win = "True" Then
    Application.Run "Dealer_wins"
Else
    Application.Run "player_wins"
End If

....
```

also, please pay attention to this line of your code:

```
Range("C18") >= Range("B18")
```

it always will be `true`, so this condition can be removed due to excessive part of code, or updated to compare `[B18]` with another cell.

Answer (score -1):

That"s why there should never be more than 10-15 lines between the beginning & the end of the element. Here, the For-Next.

As your indentation is good(kudos for that), other commenters already spotted the mistake at the end :

```
        If Range("C18") < 22 Then
            win = "Bust"
    End If
Next i
```

That should be

```
        If Range("C18") < 22 Then
            win = "Bust"
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

NB : undeleted on R3uK's demand